ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be frist statement of transaction VS ALTER SESSION statement
When Im change isolation level in plsql developer SECOND TIME then got ORA-01453: SET TRANSACTION must be first statement of transaction
Alter session statement do not begin and end any transaction himself isnt?
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=SERIALIZABLE
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=SERIALIZABLE
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=SERIALIZABLE
COMMIT
ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL=SERIALIZABLE
is the same
